# Embedded and no-embedded document in the same time

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I need to have a model which will behave like a embedded and not-embedded.

For example if I want to store this model as embedded:

```
class MenuPosition
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :category, type: String
```

I need to add

```
  embedded_in :menu
```

to it.

On the other side, if I add this line in the model I cannot store this model as not-embedded:

```
position = {
            "name" => "pork",
            "category" => "meal",
            "portion" => 100
        }
MenuPosition.create(position)
```

error message:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `new?' for nil:NilClass
```

Can I use one model for embedded and not-embedded documents?

Comment: Can you give some explanation as to why you want it to be both embedded and non-embedded? There may be a different way to achieve what you want, as I don't think this way would be either possible or advisable.

Comment: I want to have product table which would have detailed info about products (weight, size, structure and so on). User create product records once and then use this information when create product order.  Different product orders can have one product and users don't want to put all information twice.

Comment: Ok, in that case can you just use `has_many` instead of `embeds_many` so (in your example) the `Menu` would *reference* many `MenuPositions` rather than *contain* them?

Comment: In this case I need to perform two queries to get information from Menu and MenuItem. Is it right?

Comment: Yes, but is that really a problem? It's hardly any overhead and in any case it's done for you by mongoid.

Comment: It's not a problem, but I have read that it is a good practice to denoramzlize db and get all data by one query while I'm working with MongoDb

Comment: It is sometimes, but not always. The rule of thumb is that if you are always going to want the menu items for a particular menu together, make them embedded, however if you want to share menu items between menus, don't make them embedded. If there's a single field from menu item that you always access in menu you could consider denormalising that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our project we had a similar thing. What we did is define the fields as a module. A bit like this:

```
module SpecialFields
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    field :my_field, type: String
    field :my_other_field, type: String
  end
end
```

Then in your class where you want to embed, just do:

```
include SpecialFields
```

In your class that you'd like to store separately as a non-embedded document, do this:

```
class NotEmbeddedDoc
  include Mongoid::Document

  include SpecialFields
end
```

This worked pretty well in our project for a few things. However, it might not be appropriate in your case since you want to embed many. This only really works for embeds one cases I think. I have posted it here in case it helps people.